# How do I get push notifications of a specific user on Twitter?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, notifications, twitter

I heard someone mentioning you can be notified when a specific Tweeter start tweeting...but I haven't been able to find a tool that does this.  What is the way to do this without following them?

OS: 4.1
S3

Answer (score 2):

Follow them, then go to their profile and star them (it's next to the follow button).

You'll now get notifications whenever they tweet.

Comment: Will they know I've starred them as in will they I get notified when they tweet?  No way to do it without following?

Comment: They won't get notified that you starred them. You have to be following them if you're using the official Twitter app.

Comment: Oh, is there an app that does it without following?

Comment: You could try falcon pro. That lets you do it without following them

Comment: @verve That's a much more specific request than what's in your question. In general, you'll get the best answers by putting *all* your requirements in the question, so other visitors don't have to play a guessing game to try to help.

Comment: Yes, Dan I wanted to add but there is no edit button in the stackexchange app...

Comment: @verve you can edit from the stackexchange app, if you go to your question it's to the right of where your screen name appears.